# What is the syntax for IPv6 with both a zone and a range/prefix length

Tags: syntax, ipv6

I see an IPv6 address can have a range or prefix length specifier, e.g. `/64`.

I also see it can have a zone index, e.g. `%1`.

So what is the syntax when you want both? Is it `{addr}%1/64` or `{addr}/64%1` or does it not matter (or can you not have both)? Did not find any examples or explanation in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address) - they only discuss them separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prefix/mask length is just like for an IPv4 prefix/mask length, but IPv6 does not use explicit masks the way IPv4 can. For example, an IPv4 address of `10.11.12.13/24` is usually used as `10.11.12.13 255.255.255.0`, but the IPv6 address of `2001:db8::1/64` does not have a representation with an explicit mask (the mask is implied from the mask length).

A Zone ID is only used for IPv6 Link-Local addressing, which will always be in the `fe80::/64` range on each interface, and that is why you need a Zone ID to tell which interface is meant since they all use the same Link-Local network.

There would not really be a case where you combine those the way you have.